# How can I find non-ASCII characters in Codeigniter query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

The below query I have tried for mysql and it works fine but I need this in the form of codeigniter active record class.

```
SELECT name FROM tblmarkets_football WHERE name <> CONVERT(name USING ASCII);
```

I tried something like this but it's not working I'm getting 500 error.....

```
$wherestr = 'tblmarkets_football.name <>'. CONVERT(tblmarkets_football.name. ' USING ASCII');
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tblmarkets_football');
$this->db->join('tblmarkets','tblmarkets.id = tblmarkets_football.market_id','left');
$this->db->where($wherestr);
```

Comment: Don't know codeigniter or mysql but my php eye says the tick-dot (`'.`) is in the wrong place when `$wherestr` is declared.

Answer (score 0):

The Active Record allows for a Custom string within the `WHERE`, provided you've passed a `NULL` value in the condition & `FALSE` when escaping.

```
$wherestr = 
   'tblmarkets_football.name <> CONVERT(tblmarkets_football.name USING ASCII)' );
$this->db->where( $wherestr, NULL, FALSE );
```

See docs on the `->where()` method:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data